# How to refresh google map apiv2

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I have a timer.it is running every 5 minute.ı write a method called konumlarıAl in timer run method. this method get locations data from database.When konumlarıAl run,HaritaKonumGoster is method calling.I want to delete all markers and show new location data marker on map without refreshing page.

## my code

```
private void HaritaKonumGoster() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (googleHarita == null) {
            googleHarita = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.haritafragment))
                    .getMap();
            if (googleHarita != null) {
                googleHarita.clear();
                if(mrks.size()!=0)
                {
                     for (Marker marker: mrks) {
                            marker.remove();
                        }
                        mrks.clear();
                }
                googleHarita.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                Criteria criteria=new Criteria();

                String provider =locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

                Location mylocation=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                 double latitude=0;
                double longitude=0;
                double mylatitude=0;
                double myLongtitude=0;
                 //double latitude=enlem;
                    //double longitude=boylam;
                if (mylocation != null){
                    mylatitude=mylocation.getLatitude();
                    myLongtitude=mylocation.getLongitude();
                }
                BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor 
                   = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN);

                try{  
              for (int i = 0; i < degiskenler.taksici.size(); i++) {

                   latitude=Double.parseDouble(degiskenler.taksici.get(i).enlem.trim());
                   longitude=Double.parseDouble(degiskenler.taksici.get(i).boylam.trim());
                   LatLng istanbulKoordinat = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                   Marker m= googleHarita.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(istanbulKoordinat).title("Kız Kulesi").icon(bitmapDescriptor));
                   googleHarita.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(istanbulKoordinat, 7)); 
                   mrks.add(m);
               //   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"harita :)",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               }
                }
                catch(Exception exception)  {

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"harita olmadı",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                googleHarita.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(mylatitude, myLongtitude)).title("you hereeee"));
            }
        }
    }
```

## location update every 5 minute method

```
  private void LocationUpdateEvery5minute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

               zamanlayici = new Timer();
               yardimci = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
               zamanlayici.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
               {
           @Override
           public void run(){ 
                yardimci.post(new Runnable()
               {
                 public void run()
                 {  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "timera girdi",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     konumlarıAl();

         }
        });    

       }

      }, 0, ZAMAN);


            }
```

Comment: I think you need to set google map again when you want to do refresh.

Comment: when timer is running in every five minute,google map create again

Comment: Its quite confusing, can you please clear your question more clear here?

Answer (score 0):

Delete markers using

```
 googleHarita.clear()
```

[https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#clear()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#clear%28%29)

Just one call to this method should be enough to remove all the markers on your map.

Then, and add markers using

```
googleHarita.addMarker()
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html

[example here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#add_a_marker)

I don't think you need to refresh any pages.

Comment: googleHarita.clear() method didn't run.When map is refreshing,new markers added with old markers.I did not delete old markers when map is refreshing

Comment: Do you get an exception when Timer runs? And also please show a Toast after if(googleHarita != null) to see whether it runs within your Timer object. I believe your map instance is null when timer calls it. Therefore if block is not executed.

Comment: @user3452425 could you please try it out and give us a feedback?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use    **map.clear();**    which will help you to removes all markers, polylines, polygons, overlays, etc from the map.